# mysql query to fetch count of each status related to it's company courier

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have two tables

1. `company_details ---- company_id, name, address`
2. `company_courier_status ---- courier_id, company_id, status`

status column will have 0, 1, 2 values where

```
0 --- processing
1 --- success
2 --- returned
```

How to write a mysql query to get following output

```
company_name  processing  success returned
```

processing column value is count of status column value having 0
similarly for success and returned columns

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
SELECT
  a.name AS company_name,
  SUM(b.status = 0) AS processing,
  SUM(b.status = 1) AS success,
  SUM(b.status = 2) AS returned
FROM company_details a
LEFT JOIN company_courier_status b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
GROUP BY a.company_id, a.name
```